# Check multiple ids exists in Postgres int[]

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I am trying to get rows where a column of type int[] contains a value. currently i am using Any() operator but not working for me.

```
select * from products where 4 = ANY(product_type) AND (3,5) @> ANY(category_id);
```

given error:

```
Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "," LINE 1: ...mages.product_id where 4 = ANY(product_type) AND 3,5 @> ANY(category_id)
```

Comment: Try casting it, EG: `'(3,5)'::int[]`

Comment: @Usagi Miyamoto: sorry but  '(3,5)'::int[] not working for me

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto: that is an invalid cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the contains operator in a different way:

The following will test if `category_id` contains both the values 3 and 5

```
AND category_id @> array[3,5]
```

If you want to check if it contains at least one of them, use the overlaps operator:

```
AND category_id && array[3,5]
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8ddd5e90ad98a7bca9a370e74cc50946)

Comment: given error operator does not exist: integer[] = integer

Comment: @vicky793: I didn't realize `category_id` is actually an array. See my edit.

Comment: `category_id @> array[3,5]` will most certainly return those rows: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8ddd5e90ad98a7bca9a370e74cc50946

Comment: That is not the code from my answer. I wrote `category_id @> array[3,5]` you wrote `category_id @> 3,5`